# How to craft a Dockerfile for an image with NVIDIA driver/CUDA (support for tensorflow-gpu) and Python3 with pip?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I have been unsuccessful in creating a Docker image using a Dockerfile for an image which contains:

1. Python3 and pip so I can use pip to install my Python application's
   package requirements and then have access to a Python3 interpreter
   to run the app which primarily involves Keras, TensorFlow, and OpenCV
2. NVIDIA driver and CUDA support sufficient to allow for
   TensorFlow to utilize the GPU when running the application

I have tried building an image with a Dockerfile starting with a Python base image and adding the NVIDIA driver like so:

```
# minimal Python-enabled base image
FROM python:3.7

# add the NVIDIA driver
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FCAE110B1118213C
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --yes install nvidia-driver-418
```

I get a lot of output from running a `docker build` on the above Dockerfile but in the end, it gives messages that indicate that it's trying to install a later driver version that what I specified (430 instead of 418) and then it prompts for user input to set up the keyboard:

```
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.19.0-5-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-5-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.40/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-430 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-430 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up xfonts-base (1:1.0.5) ...
Setting up libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.97-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-430:
 nvidia-driver-430 depends on nvidia-dkms-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-430 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-430 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xauth (1:1.0.10-1) ...
Setting up xserver-common (2:1.20.4-1) ...
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.191) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring keyboard-configuration
----------------------------------

Please select the layout matching the keyboard for this machine.

  1. English (US)
  2. English (US) - Cherokee
  3. English (US) - English (Colemak)
  4. English (US) - English (Dvorak)
  5. English (US) - English (Dvorak, alt. intl.)
  6. English (US) - English (Dvorak, intl., with dead keys)
  7. English (US) - English (Dvorak, left-handed)
  8. English (US) - English (Dvorak, right-handed)
  9. English (US) - English (Macintosh)
  10. English (US) - English (US, alt. intl.)
  11. English (US) - English (US, euro on 5)
  12. English (US) - English (US, intl., with dead keys)
  13. English (US) - English (Workman)
  14. English (US) - English (Workman, intl., with dead keys)
  15. English (US) - English (classic Dvorak)
  16. English (US) - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)
  17. English (US) - English (programmer Dvorak)
  18. English (US) - English (the divide/multiply keys toggle the layout)
  19. English (US) - Russian (US, phonetic)
  20. English (US) - Serbo-Croatian (US)
  21. Other
Keyboard layout:
```

When I enter `1` everything appears to hang, so this isn't working yet.

I have also tried a Dockerfile beginning with an NVIDIA image and then adding Python and pip on top, like so:

```
FROM nvidia/driver:418.40.04-ubuntu18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Running `docker build` with the above gives this error:

```
Step 4/8 : RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
 ---> Running in eaa9a2ec71a9
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install python3-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What other approaches or fixes for one of the above attempts could I try?

Comment: Maybe use a Tensorflow/CUDA enabled base image instead and add Python to that if necessary? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: Thanks, @Ouroborus. When I run the Docker image that's built using this base image I get the errors indicating missing CUDA libraries (libcuda.so.1), maybe I need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable correctly to allow for finding the CUDA libraries?

Answer (score 8):

you can use this :

```
FROM nvidia/driver:418.40.04-ubuntu18.04
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && apt-get -y update \
    && add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
```